# If God is Samadarshi do prayers have any result?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, prayer

The Bhagavat Gita says, God is *samadarshi* - meaning impartial/or seeing everyone with equal vision. If He is seeing everyone equally, then what is the need of praying? How can prayers, for example praying for His grace, bring about result? Or have I misunderstood the meaning of *samadarshi*?

Comment: Ishwara is impartial. **If** Duryodhana had prayed to Him or surrendered to Him, just as Arjuna did, Duryodhana would also have been blessed by Him (subject to karma).